# Difference between Binary Search Tree and Binary Index Tree

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, binary-indexed-tree

Is Binary Index Tree and Binary Search Tree are same thing?
If not whats the actual difference between them and when to use what?

Comment: They aren't the same.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree